# Trouble with specified Postgres version and path when installing Postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

## Edit

It seems that I had conflicting versions of Postgres installed. This may help someone in the future:

What I did was first list everything Postgres related in `/usr/local/opt`

```
cd /usr/local/opt && ls
```

I had `postgis`, `postgres`, `postgresql@12`, `postgresql@13` and `postgresql@14` listed under there.

So I first removed them all,

```
rm -rf postgis postgresql postgresql@12 postgresql@13 postgresql@14
```

Then I uninstalled them via `brew`:

```
brew uninstall postgis postgresql postgresql@12 postgresql@13 postgresql@14
```

Then I reinstalled postgresql and postgis:

```
brew install postgresql@14 postgis
```

---

I ran into a weird issue today. As I often do, I have an `init.sql` script that I run each time I drop my schema and all of its tables. Everything worked fine before today, here's the error:

```
error: could not open extension control file
    "/usr/local/opt/postgresql@12/share/postgresql@12/extension/postgis.control":
        No such file or directory
```

This confused me on two levels. The first,

```
% postgres --version
postgres (PostgreSQL) 14.10 (Homebrew)
```

I'm on version 14 of Postgres, (not 12, as in the above error).

The second question is why did this happen today? I changed nothing that relates to my database or configuration.

To try to fix this error, I ran `brew install postgis` as stated in the [documentation](https://postgis.net/documentation/getting_started/install_macos/) -- something I didn't have to do before today (and everything worked just fine). But still, the line `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis` results in the error above.

How can I fix this? I'd imagine that I'd need to specify the path to Postgres 14 (not 12, as in the above error).

I checked in `/usr/local/opt/postgresql@14/share/postgresql@14/extension`, I don't see a `postgis.control` file.

Comment: There are files of Postgres you need to remove manually after removing postgres by `rm -rf ` command.

Comment: I think you're talking about [these file](https://blog.testdouble.com/posts/2021-01-28-how-to-completely-uninstall-homebrew-postgres/#:~:text=%24%20rm%20%2Drf%20/usr,f%20~/.psqlrc%20~/.psql_history) but I didn't end up needing to do this

Comment: Perhaps you might need to install postgis from source because Postgresql installation seems okay.